# Blazor - Prevent double HTTP call and wait first one

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, waithandle

In my Blazor application (WebAssembly), I need to load User data in my ApplicationState.
Many of my pages needs this User data, so on their OnAfterRenderAsync method, I'm loading User data if it's not loaded :

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        loadingSession = true;
        if (!sessionState.UserDataLoaded)
            await sessionState.LoadUserData();
        loadingSession = false;

    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

But if I go to an other page quickly, the user data won't be loaded yet, and the page will ask a new request.

So I would like to wait if there is already a request, and not to start a new one.

```
    public async Task LoadUserData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataLoading)
            {
                // Need to wait the previous request
            }

            if (dataLoaded)
                return;

            dataLoading = true;
            User = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<User>("users", options);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (User != null)
                dataLoaded = true;
            dataLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

I tried many things, ManualResetEvent, Thread.Sleep in a Task,... but I don't manage to do it correcly.
What would be the best method ?

Answer (score 0):

> [OnAfterRenderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-component-render)
> and OnAfterRender are called after a component has finished rendering.
>
> [OnInitializedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-initialization-methods)
> and OnInitialized are invoked when the component is initialized after
> having received its initial parameters from its parent component in
> SetParametersAsync.

Moving your code to the `OnInitializedAsync` method will load the user data before the control has rendered.

Edit: (*you want to pass state between components*)

[Microsoft documentation on State Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=webassembly)

Another example of keeping state in memory and passing it to components via Dependency Injection.

To make use of 'State management' you have to register a 'Service' that can be used for state management.

For example; Create a class named `AppState` with the values you would like to keep state of.

```
public class AppState
{
    public AppState()
    {
        //this class is to help maintain application state.
    }

    public UserData UserData { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherStateValue { get; set; }
}
```

then register this class in your `Services` as `Singleton` (see [Service Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes)):

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
   //...other services
   //...

   // add AppState as singleton
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppState>(); 

   //...
   //...more stuff
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Then in your `Index.razor` file (or wherever you need to call it for the first time) use *dependency injection* to get access to the `AppState` and in the `OnInitialzedAsync()` call the user data using `HttpContent`.

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.Json
@using System.Text
@inject AppState appState
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<h1>..all your html or components on the page...</h1>

@code{

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var userRequestData = new UserDataRequest(options);
    var request = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(userRequestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"api/users/", request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        appState.UserData = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<UserData>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

}
```

This will await the call to the API until it has received a response.
If the response was successful ie: `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is true. extract the data from the response message and store it in the `appState.UserDate`.

In any subsequent component you can get the `AppState` by *injecting* it using `@inject AppState appState` or if it is in a code file `[Inject] AppState appState;`

In the subsequent components you can add a check in the `OnInitializedAsync` method :

```
.
.
if (appState?.UserData == null)
{
    //appData.UserData = await request user data...
}
// more code..
.
.
```

**!! This is not how authentication should be handled though !!**

If you need authentication look at [ASP.NET Core Blazor authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as it makes use of [AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authenticationstateprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

In regards to checking if the call has already been made to the http client, the `await` should wait for the response from the `httpClient` before continuing.

If `appState.UserData` has some value then the call was successfull..

Comment: Yes i know, but I have many subComponents which call the same routine at startup, they need the user data. And with the OnInitializedAsync method, I got an exception at the first loading. 
But my question was not clear, it is "How to know if a HTTP request has already been sent, and wait it's response instead to start a new request ?"

Comment: So have you got a 'service' that acts as the application state? Do you get your user data after a login and then just need to use the user data on other components?

Comment: Yes I have a ApplicationState which store the UserData. I use IdentityServer also, but I don't know where I can Handle the login event and ask for the UserData at this moment. That's why I ask the UserData in the pages. But if I open a page and immediatly a second one, both will make the API call to obtain the UserData

Comment: So does the double load cause problems? Usually after login you will be redirected to the index page, via something like `Response.Redirect(*redirect-url*)` in login page. How do you navigate *'quickly'* to another page? by clicking a link? another tab and url? using the navbar outside the `<Authorized>` scope?

Comment: It's not really a problem, it's more an optimization. I navigate quickly by clicking in the navbar for example. And yes after login you are redirected, but to the page you asked (If you store a quick link to the dashboard page for example). 
But you make me think about a empty component in the mainLayout inside an AuthorizeView, which the unique role to load data on it's initialization. Could it be a good idea ?

Comment: You could `@inject` your httpClient and state and do a call on the `OnInitializedAsync` in the `MainLayout.Razor` file. Let me know if it works, then I'll update the answer to include that as well.

Comment: It works on the MainLayout, but only if my browser auto login. The MainLayout seems to not initialize again.
But I tried the empty component surrounded by <AuthorizeView>, and it seems to work

Comment: I have been/am still having the same issue when, though the user is authorised, the userdata is incomplete and waiting for the full user info back from the server. I already have a 'userservice' that I inject and have an event that the other components get called from if it updated. The 'getuserinfo' main call is set up in the app.razor.cs. But others have to wait or refresh when done. I was wondering if you sorted this, and if so how. I am about to have a bool in the user service that can be polled. I note you diodn't mark anything as truly answering your issue?